# Volume of solid of integration - trying to spot a silly error!

Tags: integration, exponential-function, solid-of-revolution

Here is a question:

Find the volume of the solid formed by rotating the region enclosed by the graph of the function and the $x$ axis through $2\pi$ radians about the $x$ axis in the given integral:

y = $e^{-x}$ for $x$ from $[0,1]$

I am getting the following answer:

Volume = $\int_0^1\pi e^{-2x} dx$

The antiderivative is $-\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-2x}$

I Evaluate this in the interval $0$ to $1$ and I get an answer of $-\frac{\pi}{2} (e^{-2}+1)$
However the given solution is $\frac{\pi}{2}(1-e^{-2}),$ so I am messing up my signs somewhere. Please could some body help me out! Much appreciated :).

Comment: Your antiderivative is correct, the issue comes in when you evaluate on the bounds

Comment: What should the evaluation be @StephenDonovan?

Comment: you seem to have messed up the negative sign during evaluation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the antiderivative, everything you had was correct. Carrying on from there, you would have:

$$-\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-2x}\Bigg|_0^1 = -\frac{\pi}{2}\left(e^{-2} - e^0\right) = -\frac{\pi}{2}\left(e^{-2} - 1\right)$$

which is equivalent to the given answer.

Comment: thank you for your help.